# How can I make VS Code recognize an overridden JSDoc for a re-export?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

In the following example, VS Code 1.77.3 and TypeScript 5.0.4 does not seem to pick up the `@deprecated` tag and I do not understand why? The use case is to mark the lodash `template` function as deprecated.

**t1.ts:**

```js
import _template from 'lodash/template'; // eslint-disable-line @typescript-eslint/no-restricted-imports

export {
    /** @deprecated Deprecated. Use JavaScript template string instead. */
    _template as template
};

/** @deprecated Deprecated. */
export const func = (): void => {};
```

**t2.ts:**

```js
import * as _ from './t1';

_.template('');

_.func();
```

Please also note that when using the `_.template` function VS Code correctly marks the `template` function as deprecated by crossing it out and also shows the additional comment in the help popup.

[image]

When the function has been completed it seems to forget that it is deprecated and no longer shows it crossed out.

[image]

Comment: what VS Code version are you using? Did you configure VS Code to use a workspace TypeScript SDK? If so, what version of TypeScript is installed for your workspace? (`npm list typescript`)

Comment: I'm using VS Code 1.77.3 and TypeScript 5.0.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. Now that you've shown info about how you're trying to use the function, I think I see what's going on. <sup><sub>(moral of story: save everyone their time and always start by providing a [MRE](/help/minimal-reproducible-example))</sub></sup>.

When you re-export with overridden docs, the overriding docs will only show up when you *import from the re-export*- not when you import from the original export.

---

```js
// exporter.js
/** a thing */
export const thing = "hello world!";
```

```js
// reexporter.js
export {
  /** @deprecated blah blah reasons. */
  thing
} from "./exporter";
```

```js
// importer.js
import { thing } from "./reexporter"
// ^VS Code will cross "thing" out here
import { thing as originalThing } from "./exporter"
// ^VS Code will cross nothing out here
```

To elaborate on why:

See [Override JSDoc for re-exported types / enum / classes / interfaces
#42684](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42684), where the general functionality of overriding JSDocs for re-exports was requested, and later implemented in [feat(42684): Override JSDoc for re-exported types / enum / classes / interfaces #47293](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47293). The merge of that PR into the main branch of TypeScript happened [on Jan 25th of 2022](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47293#event-5953511867). While the issue ticket and PR have no associated milestone, that's just a bit before the time that [TypeScript 4.6 Beta](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/releases/tag/v4.6-beta) was released, so I wouldn't be surprised if this functionality was in TypeScript 4.6 or 4.7.

At the time of this writing, VS Code's bundled TypeScript (which it uses by default for IntelliSense) is already at TypeScript version 5.0.

Strangely, I noticed that this feature as implemented doesn't seem to actually allow completely overriding the docs. The docs are overridden at the site of the re-export, but not at the site of the import from the re-export except that the `@deprecated` tag is added, which seems like a bug to me.

For your reference / learning purposes, this info was found by googling "`github typescript issues mark reexport as deprecated`".

I have raised a bug report of my own here: ["Overriding" JSDoc at re-exports mostly only results in propagation of added "@deprecated" JSDoc tag #53960](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/53960). The asker of the question here also raised on here: [Re-exported symbol marked with deprecated doesn't get correct deprecation highlighting #53754](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/53754) (for which [a fix has been made](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/53808)).

Comment: Thank you for the extensive feedback. I'm using the latest version of vscode and TypeScript but it does not seem to work as expected. Did you actually test it and it works in your environment? Maybe it has something to do with my specific configuration. What is really strange and suggests a possible problem in vscode is the following: while writing (even the jsdoc help includes the deprecated message) the deprecated function is correctly shown as deprecated (crossed out) but when finished editing the function is no longer marked as deprecated (no longer crossed out).

Comment: @doberkofler yes I tested and it works. notice how I don't import and then export the import though. I just `export { ... } from "...";` Maybe that has something to do with it. Or it could be a problem with your environment, in which case I'd suggest you ask a new question post where you try to provide _as much info as possible_ about that specific problem.

Comment: @doberkofler see my edited answer. I also made a fix to the re-export code I wrote. I was missing the `from` part of the re-export (sorry).

Comment: I know, there should always be an MRE, but at the beginning everything seems to simple ;-) I now edited my original question with the exact files needed to reproduce my problem. Unfortunately I'm still unable to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
import _template from 'lodash/template';

export {
/** @deprecated Deprecated. Use JavaScript template string instead. */
_template as template
};
```

Comment: Does not seem to work